# ViewBinding not working Creating Android Calculator APP

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I was doing an APP following this tutorial ---
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTyyNpY7hy0

Ofc the code was deprecated since it uses android.extensions,
so i decided to go with the updated implementation by using viewBinding

however the after running the buttons are not working and thus text is not being displayed in the output

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.thomas.calculadoracompleta.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.Expression
import java.lang.Exception
import java.text.DecimalFormat

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.buttonClear.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = ""
            binding.output.text = ""

        }

        binding.buttonBracketLeft.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("(")

        }

        binding.buttonBracketRight.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText(")")

        }

        binding.buttonDivision.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("÷")

        }

        binding.button7.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("7")

        }

        binding.button8.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("8")

        }

        binding.button9.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("9")

        }

        binding.buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("×")

        }

        binding.button4.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("4")

        }

        binding.button5.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("5")

        }

        binding.button6.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("6")

        }

        binding.buttonSubtraction.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("-")

        }

        binding.button5.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("1")

        }

        binding.button4.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("2")

        }

        binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("3")

        }

        binding.buttonAddition.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("+")

        }

        binding.button0.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText("0")

        }

        binding.buttonDot.setOnClickListener {
            binding.input.text = addToInputText(".")

        }

        binding.buttonEquals.setOnClickListener {
            showResult()

        }

    }

    private fun addToInputText(buttonValue: String): String {
        return "${binding.input.text}$buttonValue"
    }

    private fun getInputExpression(): String {
        var expression = binding.input.text.replace(Regex("÷"), "/")
        expression = expression.replace(Regex("×"),"*")
        return expression
    }

    private fun showResult(){

        try {
            val expression = getInputExpression()
            val result = Expression(expression).calculate()
            if(result.isNaN()){
                binding.output.text = "Error"
            } else {
                binding.output.text = DecimalFormat("0.######").format(result).toString()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){

        }

    }
```

the problem is that buttons aren't working.

i'll add the xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/window_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:background="@color/io_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="5+10-3" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            tools:text="12" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="C"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_bracket_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="("/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_bracket_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text=")"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_division"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="÷"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="7" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="8"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="9"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="×"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="4"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="5"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="6"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_subtraction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="-"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="1"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="2"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="3"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_addition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="+"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="0"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_dot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="."/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_equals"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height= "90dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Button_Style"
                android:text="="/>

        </TableRow>




    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
´´´
```

Comment: Define "not working".  Are they not appearing?  Are the click handlers not being called?  Are the click handlers being called but they don't do what you expect?

Comment: 1 they are appearing, but click handlers are not being called

Answer (score 0):

put your binding inside activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   // Here
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a XML problem fixed it after and now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).